# How can I render a D3 Force-Bubble in combination with React?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

I'm trying to convert a d3 bubble example from d3-dominant to a react-D3 combination.

- I've gotten bubble to render in React
- I'm having trouble getting the d3 '.on('tick',...' to work & somehow update some '' components.

Here's a D3 - dominant example:
https://codepen.io/mretfaster/pen/rqagXX
The tick function is whats getting in translation from D3 to D3+React. The tick updates the cx & cy...

```
    let myTickFn = () => {
    circlesObj.attr("cx",d => d.x)
      .attr("cy",d => d.y)
  }
```

Here's the D3+React example, where the farthest I've gotten is a console.log on tick..
https://codepen.io/mretfaster/pen/mzyZPq?editors=0111
Here's where I'm stuck...

```
//setup simulation
    let sim = this.makeD3Simulation();
    sim.force("myCollide", d3.forceCollide(d => this.radiusScale(+d.sales)))
  .alpha(.5)
  .nodes(this.dummyData)
  .on('tick', this.resizeTick);
```

the resizeTick function doesn't seem to pass an event or the 'd' values the same way in React as it does in the D3-dominant example.

Thanks ahead of time for anyone who can help :)

Comment: you haven't bound any data to the circles, how do you think to update the position based on the force simulation

Comment: hello rio, thanks for the feedback, I've gotten the circles to render with data from the simulation nodes. I just can't get them to *move* once rendered, though.

Comment: what do you expect `e` to be? in you d3 version your tick callback has no parameters, why should it have in the react version?

Comment: yes yes, I've tried this without the e and nothing happens there either :/